# Doubt regarding probability calculation of an example problem from Sheldon Ross.

Tags: probability

**The problem under consideration is:**

A crime has been committed by a solitary individual, who left some DNA at the
scene of the crime. Forensic scientists who studied the recovered DNA noted that 
only five strands could be identified and that each innocent person, independently,
would have a probability of $10^{−5}$ of having his or her DNA match on all five strands.
The district attorney supposes that the perpetrator of the crime could be any of the
one million residents of the town. Ten thousand of these residents have been released
from prison within the past 10 years; consequently, a sample of their DNA is on file.
Before any checking of the DNA file, the district attorney feels that each of the ten
thousand ex-criminals has probability α of being guilty of the new crime, while each
of the remaining 990,000 residents has probability β, where α = cβ. (That is, the
district attorney supposes that each recently released convict is c times as likely to
be the crime’s perpetrator as is each town member who is not a recently released
convict.) When the DNA that is analyzed is compared against the database of the
ten thousand ex-convicts, it turns out that A. J. Jones is the only one whose DNA
matches the profile. Assuming that the district attorney’s estimate of the relationship
between α and β is accurate, what is the probability that A. J. is guilty?

**Problematic Part of Solution**

*In order to calculate conditional probability, there is the following intermediate step*

Now, let G be the event that A. J. is guilty, and let M denote the event that A. J. is
the only one of the ten thousand on file to have a match.

If A. J. is guilty, then he will be the only one to have a DNA match
if none of the others on file have a match. Therefore,
$$P(M|G) = (1 − 10^{−5})^{9999}$$
On the other hand, if A. J. is innocent, then in order for him to be the only match, his
DNA must match (which will occur with probability $10^{−5}$), all others in the database
must be innocent, and none of these others can have a match.

Now, given that A. J.
is innocent, the conditional probability that all the others in the database are also
innocent is
$$P(all\ others\ innocent\ |AJ\ innocent) = \frac{P(all\ in\ database\ innocent\ )}{
P(AJ\ innocent)}$$
$$ = \frac{1 − 10,000α}{1-\alpha}$$

**Doubt**

Why is ${P(all\ in\ database\ innocent\ )} = 1 − 10,000α $. Shouldn't it be $$(1-\alpha)^{10,000}$$.

**Reference**- Sheldon Ross, 8th Edition, Example $3o$.

Comment: Quick comment... the reference is by a single author. (: Sheldon M. Ross

Comment: Thanks..Changed it. It just has become a habit of mine to say, Sheldon and Ross. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what is going on:  From the problem statement, it appears that we are to assume that there is one and only one perpetrator.  Therefore the guilt or innocence of different individuals are not independent events.  In fact the guilt of individual x is mutually exclusive of the guilt of individual y (provided x and y are different people).

Thus the probability that the guilty person is one of the released felons is $\alpha+\alpha+\cdot+\alpha = 10000\alpha$.  Hence the probability that none of them is guilty is $1-10000\alpha$.

Comment: So you mean to say that we should consider them as dependent but mutually exclusive cases?

Comment: Yes. The guilt of various people in the town are pairwise mutually exclusive.

Comment: In fact, the problem explicitly says that the crime has been committed by a solitary individual.